# sum on having count more than 1

Tags: sql

Currently I execute below code

```
select  system,aid,mid,buysell,sdate,medate,namount,type, count(*)
from databasefile
where mid in ('123456')
group by  system,aid,mid,buysell,sdate,medate,namount,type
order by aid
```

I get below data 
'''
[image]

I want to insert a difference field, which is calculated as [(namount for system a) - (namount for system z) ]. namount for system z is calculated as (total namount for buys - total namounts for sells).

please help me get a sql to achieve this, thanks very much and I sincerely appreciate your help.

Comment: (1) Edit your question and show the results that you want.  (2) Give an example of the calculation; the explanation is not clear.  (3) Provide a database tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> calculated as [(namount for system a) - (namount for system z) ]

If this is what you want, you can use window functions:

```
select system, aid, mid, buysell, sdate, medate, namount, type, count(*),
       (sum(case when system = 'a' then namount else 0 end) over () -
        sum(case when system = 'z' then namount else 0 end) over ()
       )
from databasefile
where mid in ('123456')
group by system, aid, mid, buysell, sdate, medate, namount, type
order by aid
```

Comment: namount for system z  should be calculated as (total namount for buys - total namount for sells)

Comment: @user8371676 . . . That is very confusing.  `namount` is already a column in the data.

Comment: You just need to flip the sign on sells.

Comment: difference for 999_AUD is (100-(2*100- 1*100.101)) = 0.101